# Simple copy of formula from 1 worksheet to another without getting a #ref error

Tags: excel, vba

This should be I hope a simple question.

I have a simple formula in a cell, worksheet name is Entry

`=Entry!D10`

I have 5 cells all with similar formulas in them. I want to be able to push a `form button` and copy the results from these formulas to a new row on another worksheet.

Comment: Hi Mark: are your formula cells in a column or in a row?  In what cells are they?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to port across formulas without getting the #ref error

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ws1.Range("A1").Formula = ws2.Range("C1").Formula
    ws1.Range("D1").Formula = ws2.Range("F1").Formula
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank Sid this worked I had to reverse the ws2 range = ws1 range but got the needed result. thank you